# How to convert int to char with leading zeros?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to convert int datafield to nvarchar with leading zeros

example:

1 convert to '001'

867 convert to '000867', etc.

thx.

---

This is my response 4 Hours later ...

I tested this T-SQL Script and work fine for me !

```
DECLARE @number1 INT, @number2 INT

SET @number1 = 1

SET @number2 = 867

SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST(@number1 AS NCHAR(3)), 3 ) AS NUMBER_CONVERTED

SELECT RIGHT('000000' + CAST(@number2 AS NCHAR(6)), 6 ) AS NUMBER_CONVERTED
```

---

I created this user function

T-SQL Code :

```
CREATE FUNCTION CIntToChar(@intVal BIGINT, @intLen Int) RETURNS nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

    -- BIGINT = 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) Max size number

    -- @intlen contains the string size to return
    IF @intlen > 20
       SET @intlen = 20

    RETURN REPLICATE('0',@intLen-LEN(RTRIM(CONVERT(nvarchar(20),@intVal)))) 
        + CONVERT(nvarchar(20),@intVal)

END
```

Example :

SELECT dbo.CIntToChar(  867,  6  ) AS COD_ID

OUTPUT

000867

Comment: In your first sample CASTs should be NVARCHAR instead of NCHAR types, because NCHAR(3) has always lenght of 3.

Answer (score 126):

Try this: `select right('00000' + cast(Your_Field as varchar(5)), 5)`

It will get the result in 5 digits, ex: 00001,...., 01234

Comment: Note that for postgres you'll need to replace the + with ||, so ```select right('00000' || cast(Your_Field as varchar(5)), 5)```

Answer (score 75):

You can also use **FORMAT()** function introduced in **SQL Server 2012**.
http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh213505.aspx

```
DECLARE @number1 INT, @number2 INT

SET @number1 = 1
SET @number2 = 867

SELECT FORMAT(@number1, 'd10')
SELECT FORMAT(@number2, 'd10')
```

Comment: I will concur on the SQL2012, but for those SQL 2008r2 and older, my solution will get the result

Comment: Just tested FORMAT Sql Server 2012 - it is slow, as in "one number per several seconds" slow. Stay away.

Comment: @Muposat, can you please provide the code for that test? It's very important. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Diomedes Domínguez it has been a year, so I no longer have the original test. I just run another test on a really fast server, and got 32 seconds to format 1 million numbers. Not the end of the world, but solution posted by Nguyen Tran does it in 1 second. To test simply create a loop from @i int = 0 to 10000000.

Answer (score 24):

Use `REPLICATE` so you don't have to hard code all the leading zeros:

```
DECLARE @InputStr int
       ,@Size     int
SELECT @InputStr=123
      ,@Size=10

PRINT REPLICATE('0',@Size-LEN(RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(8000),@InputStr)))) + CONVERT(varchar(8000),@InputStr)
```

OUTPUT:

```
0000000123
```

Answer (score 17):

Not to High-Jack this question but the note needs to be made that you need to use (N)VARCHAR instead of (N)CHAR data-type.

```
RIGHT('000' + CAST(@number1 AS NCHAR(3)), 3 )
```

Above segment, will not produce the correct response from SQL 2005

```
RIGHT('000' + CAST(@number1 AS NVARCHAR(3)), 3 )
```

Above segment, will produce the desired response from SQL 2005

The the varchar will provide you with the desired prefix length on the fly.
Where as the fixed length data type will require length designation and adjustments.

Answer (score 9):

I like to use

```
DECLARE @Length int
DECLARE @Number int
SET @Length = 9
SET @Number = 4

select right( POWER(10, @Length) + @Number, @Length)
```

this gives me

```
000000004
```

Comment: Feels a bit hacky, but it worked for me in DB2. I couldn't get the answers above to work.

Comment: I like it, too. If the Length is hardcoded, you can just use `RIGHT(1000+Number, 3)` - nice, short and fast

Comment: This works on all SQL Server variants from 2005 onwards. Preferred answer.

Comment: What's the 10 mean?

Comment: @Fandango68 The '10' in 'POWER(10, @Length)' above is because we use base 10 arithmetic - so the '1000' literal in maf-soft answer above is equivalent to POWER(10, 3) - 10^3 = 1000.

Answer (score 5):

Data type "int" cannot be more than 10 digits, additionally the "Len()" function works on ints, so there's no need to convert the int to a string before calling the len() function.

Lastly, you are not taking into account the case where the size of your int > the total number of digits you want it padded to (@intLen).

Therefore, a more concise / correct solution is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION rf_f_CIntToChar(@intVal Int, @intLen Int) RETURNS nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @intlen > 20 SET @intlen = 20
    IF @intlen < LEN(@intVal) RETURN RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @intVal), @intlen)
    RETURN REPLICATE('0', @intLen - LEN(@intVal)) + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @intVal)
END
```

Answer (score 5):

Not very elegant, but I add a set value with the same number of leading zeroes I desire to the numeric I want to convert, and use RIGHT function.

Example:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(7),1000000 + @number2),6)
```

> Result: '000867'

Answer (score 3):

One line solution (*per se*) for SQL Server 2008 or above:

```
DECLARE @DesiredLenght INT = 20;
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        REPLICATE(
            '0',
            (@DesiredLenght-LEN([Column])) * (1+SIGN(@DesiredLenght-LEN([Column])) / 2) ),
        [Column])
FROM Table;
```

Multiplication by `SIGN` expression is equivalent to `MAX(0, @DesiredLenght-LEN([Column]))`. The problem is that `MAX()` accepts only one argument...

Answer (score 3):

Works in SQLServer

```
declare @myNumber int = 123
declare @leadingChar varchar(1) = '0'
declare @numberOfLeadingChars int = 5

select right(REPLICATE ( @leadingChar , @numberOfLeadingChars ) + cast(@myNumber as varchar(max)), @numberOfLeadingChars)
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue, this is how I resolved... Simple and elegant. The "4" is how long the string should be, no matter what length of integer is passed it will pad with zero's up to "4".

```
STUFF(SomeVariableOrField,1,0,REPLICATE('0',4 - LEN(SomeVariableOrField)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wanted my field to have leading 0's  in 10 character field (NVARCHAR(10)).
The source file does not have the leading 0's needed to then join to in another table.
Did this simply due to being on SQL Server 2008R2:

**Set Field = right(('0000000000' + [Field]),10)**  (Can't use Format() as this is pre SQL2012)

Performed this against the existing data.  So this way 1 or 987654321 will still fill all 10 spaces with leading 0's.

As the new data is being imported & then dumped to the table through an Access database, I am able to use Format([Field],"0000000000") when appending from Access to the SQL server table for any new records.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select right('000' + convert(varchar(3),id),3) from table

    example
    declare @i int
    select @i =1

select right('000' + convert(varchar(3),@i),3)
```

BTW if it is an int column then it will still not keep the zeros
Just do it in the presentation layer or if you really need to in the
SELECT

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @number1 INT, @number2 INT

SET @number1 = 1

SET @number2 = 867
```

-- Without the 'RTRIM', the value returned is `3__` !!!

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + RTRIM(CAST(@number1 AS NCHAR(3)), 3 )) AS NUMBER_CONVERTED
```

-- Without the 'RTRIM', the value returned is `867___` !!!

```
SELECT RIGHT('000000' + RTRIM(CAST(@number2 AS NCHAR(6)), 6 )) AS NUMBER_CONVERTED
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me in MYSQL:

```
FUNCTION leadingZero(format VARCHAR(255), num VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
  return CONCAT(SUBSTRING(format,1,LENGTH(format)-LENGTH(num)),num);
END
```

For example:

```
leadingZero('000',999); returns '999'
leadingZero('0000',999); returns '0999'
leadingZero('xxxx',999); returns 'x999'
```

Hope this will help.
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Using `RIGHT` is a good option but you can also do the following:

```
SUBSTRING(CAST((POWER(10, N) + value) AS NVARCHAR(N + 1)), 2, N)
```

where `N` is the total number of digits you want displayed.  So for a 3-digit value with leading zeros (`N = 3`):

```
SUBSTRING(CAST((POWER(10, 3) + value) AS NVARCHAR(4)), 2, 3)
```

or alternately

```
SUBSTRING(CAST(1000 + value) AS NVARCHAR(4)), 2, 3)
```

What this is doing is adding the desired value to a power of 10 large enough to generate enough leading zeros, then chopping off the leading 1.

The advantage of this technique is that the result will always be the same length, allowing the use of `SUBSTRING` instead of `RIGHT`, which is not available in some query languages (like HQL).

Answer (score -1):

I was wondering, would this be on any use to you?

```
declare @val int,@len=800
select replace(str(@val,@len),' ','0')
```