# Convert trims off leading zeros

Tags: t-sql

You'd think the two would both bring up the same result.  But this doesn't because the convert is trimming off the 2 zeros hence the 2nd doesn't return results as it's comparing 446641 to 446641

```
select memberID, 
            Photo as PhotoBlob 
    from    SomeTable
WHERE memberId = '00446641'

Select  memberID, 
        Photo as PhotoBlob 
from    SomeTable
WHERE memberId = convert(char(13), 00446641) - this is trimming off the 2 zeros
```

memberID for whatever odd reason isn't an int, it's a char(13) in that table

UPDATE

Here's the context:

```
public static MemberPhoto RetrieveMemberPhotoFromBlob(Int64 contractNumber)
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(Config.DbConnectionString_MemberPhotos);

    using ( DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(string.Format(@" Select  memberID, 
                                                                            Photo as PhotoBlob 
                                                                    from    SomeTable
                                                                    WHERE memberId = convert(char(13), @{0})","memberID")))
    {
        try
        {
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@contractNumber", DbType.Int64, contractNumber);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert int to char with leading zeros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397161/how-to-convert-int-to-char-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: I don't like that solution, it's hard coding the 000..how do you know how many leading zeros you'll have?  You don't, this isn't dynamic enough on that other thread you're showing.

Comment: all I'm trying to do is figure out how to keep the same number in tact, leading zeros or not when converting to char.

Comment: "The same number"? 446641 *is* the same number as 00446641 in the integer world. So, I'll pose the same question back: how do you know how many leading zeroes you'll have?

Comment: And please read my question, it's nothing like what that other post is asking.  That other post is asking how to APPEND zeros.  I'm asking how to RETAIN existing leading zeros during a char conversion.  Don't be so trigger happy to close stuff.

Comment: Well, aside from the obvious answer, "Don't use `convert`, use a pair of single quotes (`'00446641'`) instead", or you could convert the other side to an int - but I'm guessing you don't want that either, because it sounds like "00446641" is a different value than "0446641" - the only option *is* to append zeroes to it...

Comment: Doesn't your question contain a working answer, though? Enclose the string in quotation marks, and you'll preserve everything in between the quotation marks.

Comment: May I ask why you want to convert anyway since the first approach works?

Comment: I'm sending in an int memberId from C# (datareader) so I am doing the conversion in T-SQL so it matches memberID by string, not by int

Comment: Sorry, but still not clear. If the value is sent as an integer, do you think it arrives zero-padded and *then* gets stripped off of the leading zeros?

Comment: I'll update the post, and give more context to help

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't make sense. your int `contractNumber` can never, and will never, have leading zeroes. It's an `Int64`. There's nothing being "trimmed off" here. So please post all the code going back until the point where you have some input with said leading zeroes.

Comment: You cannot use an integer in your UI code to represent a char(13) field if that field contains meaningful leading/trailing 0s.  It's a char field.  It's not an int field.  Use a string in your model.  This is a somewhat classic mistake, like trying to use an int to represent a phone number.  You just can't do it - some people may put a leading 0 in front of the phone number, phone numbers end with 0, etc.

Comment: @Brian, yea this makes my CRUD code a pain in the ass.  Because I have to convert the string to an Int64 in the end if I want to work with the freakin returned ID in my code as an Int64...so I end up having to do a damn parse on the string when it comes back.  Totally unnecessary cast if it were designed right in the DB

Comment: Brian can you use your latest comment up here as the answer and I'll mark it as the answer...

Comment: Why do you want to treat this as an int64 in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Per request,

You cannot use an integer in your UI code to represent a char(13) field if that field contains meaningful leading/trailing 0s. It's a char field. It's not an int field. Use a string in your model. This is a somewhat classic mistake, like trying to use an int to represent a phone number. You just can't do it - some people may put a leading 0 in front of the phone number, phone numbers end with 0, etc