# sql select parent child recursive in one field

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I do not know how to select query recursive..

```
 id     idparent    jobNO
--------------------------------
  1         0         1
  2         1         2
  3         1         3
  4         0         4
  5         4         5
  6         4         6
```

how do the results like this With SqlServer

```
 id     idparent    jobNO   ListJob
----------------------------------------
  1         0         1        1
  2         1         2        1/2
  3         1         3        1/3
  4         0         4        4
  5         4         5        4/5
  6         5         6        4/5/6
```

Comment: You should tell us which version of SQL you are using (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.).

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on "*With SqlServer*"

Comment: Unrelated, but: why aren't you using a proper foreign key constraint from `idparent` to `id`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to use a Recursive Common Table Expression.

There are many useful articles online.

Useful Links

[Simple Talk: SQL Server CTE Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/)

[blog.sqlauthority: Recursive CTE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/)

Here is a solution to your question:

```
   CREATE TABLE #TEST
    (
        id int not null,
        idparent int not null,
        jobno int not null
    );

    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES 
    (1,0,1),
    (2,1,2),
    (3,1,3),
    (4,0,4),
    (5,4,5),
    (6,5,6);

    WITH CTE AS (
-- This is end of the recursion: Select items with no parent
        SELECT id, idparent, jobno, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),jobno) AS ListJob
        FROM #Test
        WHERE idParent = 0
    UNION ALL
-- This is the recursive part: It joins to CTE
        SELECT t.id, t.idparent, t.jobno,  c.ListJob + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),t.jobno) AS ListJob
        FROM #Test t
        INNER JOIN CTE c ON t.idParent = c.id
    )
    SELECT * FROM CTE
    ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: If you want to have a correct, stable sort order (i. e. as the tree would look like expanded), change `ORDER BY id` to `ORDER BY ListJob` and use `FORMAT(jobno, 'd10')` and `FORMAT(t.jobno, 'd10')` instead of the  `CONVERT` calls ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18301526/107625) for the `FORMAT` call).

Comment: how to handle infinite loops?

Comment: If a CTE is created incorrectly it can enter an infinite loop. To prevent this, the MAXRECURSION hint can be added in the OPTION clause of the primary SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement. (Found here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cte-in-sql/ )