# SQL Server - Concatenate all child parent relationships into a single string

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem:
I have a table that has family trees that has parents and child elements.  What I need to return is the family tree for each child.  I cant figure out how to do this with a cte or alike

Table:

| ID | Name | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Child1 | 2 |
| 2 | parent1 | 3 |
| 3 | Grandparent1 | null |
| 4 | Child2 | 5 |
| 5 | parent2 | null |
| 6 | Child3 | null |

Expected results:

| ID | Family |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | grandparent1, parent1 |
| 2 | grandparent1 |
| 3 | null |
| 4 | parent2 |
| 5 | null |
| 6 | null |

Comment: How are you determining the relationship here? If it's based on the name, `'Parent1'` relates to `1`, then you have a design flaw. The Name and the "parent" need to be separate columns.

Comment: What's MSSQL version do you have ?

Comment: As for the problem, if you fix your design, you'll find plenty of examples here on  [so] on how to recurse through a hierarchy and how to create delimited data; what were wrong with all those existing answers? Which did you look at, and what about them didn't you understand?

Comment: There's no hierarchy here. Just IDs and names. If you want to specify a hierarchy, the fastest way is to use [the hierarchyid type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/tutorial-using-the-hierarchyid-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) which is available in all supported SQL Server versions. A CTE can work if you only have `ID` and `ParentID` columns, but won't be as fast as using a `hierarchyid`.

Comment: With hierarchyid, if you want to [find all children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/lesson-2-creating-and-managing-data-in-a-hierarchical-table?view=sql-server-ver15#find-subordinate-nodes) you could use `WHERE OrgNode.IsDescendantOf(@CurrentEmployee ) = 1`

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, `'parent1'` has no relation to `'grandparent1'`. According to your poor design choice, both are the "parent" of `'child1'`, which is also the parent of itself? The data, in truth, is very wrong and needs fixing.

Comment: Apologies for messy post.
MSSQL 2017,    updated the post to include the ID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql select parent child recursive in one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679357/sql-select-parent-child-recursive-in-one-field)

Comment: I'm a little baffled by all the downvotes.  The question seems clear and the answer is not obvious.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Initially missed a column with the post.  so was bit confusing.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a recursive CTE.  The tricky part is removing the current name from the `family` list.

The following approach uses the recursive CTE to generate all family members and then returns the current name.  If the names can overlap significantly (such as "grandchild1" and "child1"), then it might need to be tweaked.  But it works for your example:

```
with cte as (
      select id, name, convert(varchar(max), ',' + name) as family, 1 as lev
      from t
      where parent is null
      union all
      select t.id, t.name, concat(cte.family, ',', t.name), lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on t.parent = cte.id
     )
select id, name,
       stuff(nullif(replace(family, ',' + name, ''), ''), 1, 1, '') as familh
from (select cte.*, max(lev) over (partition by id) as max_lev
      from cte
     ) cte
where lev = max_lev;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9bf485e1e7f5d8f46b31a03d625011d2) is a little db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for this,  busy tweaking a bit but seems it works.